# Why am I getting a Parser Error when i follow this example?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I followed these instructions here: http://w3schools.com/razor/razor_example.asp
NOTE: I'm using Web Matrix

The example said to do this:

```
@
{
var imagePath; 
if( Request["Choice"] != null)
{imagePath="images\" + Request["Choice"];} 
} 
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<body> 
<h1>Display Images</h1> 
<form method="post" action=""> 
<div>
   I want to see: 
   <select name="Choice"> 
      <option value="Photo1.jpg">Photo 1</option> 
      <option value="Photo2.jpg">Photo 2</option> 
      <option value="Photo3.jpg">Photo 3</option> 
   </select> 
   &nbsp; 
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" /> 
</div> 
<div style="padding:10px;"> 
@if(imagePath != "")
{<img src="@imagePath" alt="Sample" />} 
</div> 
</form> 
</body> 
</html>
```

And all i get this this error:

Does anything have to be setup to accept @ { being on seperate lines?

```
    Server Error in '/' Application.
    Parser Error 
    Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource
    required to service this request. Please review the following 
    specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 

    Parser Error Message: A space or line break was encountered after
    the "@" character.  Only valid identifiers, keywords, comments, 
    "(" and "{" are valid at the start of a code block and they must 
    occur immediately following "@" with no space in between.


    Source Error: 


    Line 1:  @
    Line 2:  {
    Line 3:  var imagePath; 


    Source File: /Page.cshtml    Line: 1 


    Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.1
```

If I put them on the same line, i get this error:

```
    Parser Error 
    Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 

    Parser Error Message: The code block is missing a closing "}" character.  Make sure you have a matching "}" character for all the "{" characters within this block, and that none of the "}" characters are being interpreted as markup.


    Source Error: 


    Line 1:  @{
    Line 2:  var imagePath; 
    Line 3:  if( Request["Choice"] != null)


    Source File: /Page.cshtml    Line: 1
```

I don't know whats wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to fix the couple of errors in your code:

```
@{
    var imagePath = ""; 
    if(Request["Choice"] != null) {
        imagePath = "images/" + Request["Choice"];
    } 
} 
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<body> 
<h1>Display Images</h1> 
<form method="post" action=""> 
<div>
   I want to see: 
   <select name="Choice"> 
      <option value="Photo1.jpg">Photo 1</option> 
      <option value="Photo2.jpg">Photo 2</option> 
      <option value="Photo3.jpg">Photo 3</option> 
   </select> 
   &nbsp; 
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" /> 
</div> 
<div style="padding:10px;"> 
    @if(imagePath != "") {
        <img src="@imagePath" alt="Sample" />
    } 
</div> 
</form> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: ok, this worked, thanks.. i guess the folks at w3schools.com had wrong code? it worked in their example, but not here?  was it a setting that has to be done to work like their example in the url?

Comment: @Jeremy, the example at W3Schools is WRONG. This shouldn't be something that must surprise you. This site is not the best source of information I would pick for learning :-)

Answer (score 5):

Some people will stumble across this answer with just copying code samples from jquery.com into a razor file.   For example I was testing something out and got the error from a long javascript variable value a regular expression specifically.

```
 emailRegex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$/,
```

Notice the @@  , I had to add the second @ to escape .... otherwise I get the error above and thus a google search shows me this stackoverflow page in the top result.  So while this does not directly answer the question, I'm quite sure it could help someone else.

Comment: this just happened to me! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove line break after @ character.change you code like this

```
    @{
    var imagePath;
////other things..
```

here is a good syntax reference for you http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx
and you need to change these lines too,

```
@{if(imagePath != "")

<img src="@imagePath" alt="Sample" />

}
```

Comment: that returns an error as well, see error i just posted above.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is wrong at `var imagePath;`
You can not declare with `var` without assigning a value.
Just change it to: 
`var imagePath = "";`

or
`string imagePath;`